when i want to update the quantity in the cart page in magento 2 its not updated Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1
I have used this code to print the data in the cart parameter
echo "<pre>";
            $cartData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cart');
            print_r($cartData);

the output is like this in the nested array, the inner array does not contain data it contains a string
Array
(
    [504102] => Array
)

Expected output:
Array 
(
      [2283] => Array  
                ( 
                  [qty] => 2 
                ) 
)


Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost
https://prnt.sc/hZ2zJG-QPzQb
https://prnt.sc/zXSB84YPJuNY
